# Mailman add user via email

Tags: email, administration, mailman

I currently manage a mailing list hosted on a mailman service.

I'd like to be able to add new users to this mailing list by sending an appropriate email to the mailman service.
Is there a tool for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific commands can be sent to: listname-request@doma.in (note the `-request` appended to the list name)

The mail should have no subject and the following body:

```
   subscribe [password] [digest|nodigest] [address=<addres@doma.in>]
```

`<>` fields are mandatory, `[]` fields are optional.